# Unable to access scope variable inside $watch

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am developing one filter in **angularJS**. Everything is working fine but only in one place I am unable to access the scope object but when I change the code it is working fine but I want to know what is the problem.I think my understanding is wrong about scope and directives.

inside one directive I am accessing one array and in scope.watch function I try to access that array but it is not working

working code

```
var currentScope=scope.mainList[scope.$index].list;
//this will hit whenever any of the scope variable changes
scope.$watch(function () {
  var hasTrue, hasFalse;
  angular.forEach(currentScope, function (v) {
    if (v["isSelected"]) {
      hasTrue = true;
    } else {
      hasFalse = true;
    }
  });
  if (hasTrue && hasFalse) {
    iElement.attr('checked', false);
   // iElement.addClass('greyed');
  } else {
    iElement.attr('checked', hasTrue);
   // iElement.removeClass('greyed');
  }
}, true);
```

this is not working

```
var currentScope=scope.mainList[scope.$index].list;
 //this will hit only when this corresponding scope variable changes
scope.$watch(currentScope,function (newVal) {
  var hasTrue, hasFalse;
  angular.forEach(newVal, function (v) {
    if (v["isSelected"]) {
      hasTrue = true;
    } else {
      hasFalse = true;
    }
  });
  if (hasTrue && hasFalse) {
    iElement.attr('checked', false);
   // iElement.addClass('greyed');
  } else {
    iElement.attr('checked', hasTrue);
   // iElement.removeClass('greyed');
  }
}, true);
```

I need this second code but whenever I changes any of the variables it is not hitting and its coming undefined

please check this bellow link it will give more idea.....

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/ogusLrez/)

Comment: which variable is not accessible in second code?

Comment: @Jigar7521:   in first code we are watching entire scope but in second one only the specific array but this second one is not hitting,please check my fiddle u will understand the problem

Comment: You are **not** watching the entire scope in the first example. You are watching the provided function for changes in its return value. Please read about $watch here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope. It takes an expression first (either string or function), and the second argument is the listener (called by angular when it detects changes in the expression).

You might have got the idea, that your code is called for each change in the scope, but angular will call this function mutliple times to detect changes in the expression.

Comment: @Tobi: then what is the solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @tobi’s comment, here is the recommended way to have written your watch function:

```
var currentScope=scope.mainList[scope.$index].list;
scope.$watch(function () { return currentScope; }, function (newVal) {
  var hasTrue = false, hasFalse = false;
  angular.forEach(newVal, function (v) {
    if (v["isSelected"]) {
      hasTrue = true;
    } else {
      hasFalse = true;
    }
  });
  if (hasTrue && hasFalse) {
    iElement.attr('checked', false);
   // iElement.addClass('greyed');
  } else {
    iElement.attr('checked', hasTrue);
   // iElement.removeClass('greyed');
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
scope.currentScope=scope.mainList[scope.$index].list;
scope.$watch('currentScope', function (newVal) {
  var hasTrue = false, hasFalse = false;
  angular.forEach(newVal, function (v) {
    if (v["isSelected"]) {
      hasTrue = true;
    } else {
      hasFalse = true;
    }
  });
  if (hasTrue && hasFalse) {
    iElement.attr('checked', false);
   // iElement.addClass('greyed');
  } else {
    iElement.attr('checked', hasTrue);
   // iElement.removeClass('greyed');
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks..its working fine the problem with my previous code is whenever any change in any of the scope will hit that watch function now that issue solved....

Comment: can u explain why this one scope.$watch(currentScope,function (newVal) {} is not working

Comment: @user it's not working because you are not really providing an expression to the $watch. You are providing an already evaluated result, which will never change. The two examples 2ps gave are the two ways i would do this. Either provide a string, which contains an expression that can be evaluated inside the current scope (either logical or just the name of an object like above) or you provide a function, that will be called mutliple times by angular. Once the return value changes from expression or function, angular will call your listener.